# Xamarin Forms Platform Android: View loading complete

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to find out, if the view is completely loaded? I have to add some custom views with a calculated size based on the the parent view.
I tried OnAppearing (called before), SizeChanged (called multiple), SizeAllocated etc. I tried to add an invisible switch with bounded property, but sized of the parent are wrong. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such callback. But would you mind to use adaptive layout for purpose? For example use `Grid` as parent and use `RowDefinition` and `ColumnDefinition` to let the children auto adapt to the parent view.

Comment: I think that would not be a solution for my problem of resizing images to its calculated view size, but I found another solution.